# How to improve this code to print a triangle of numbers?

Tags: java

I am a beginner and have just started to code. I wrote this getting below mentioned output and also got a result. But I have a feeling my code is not efficient, could anyone kindly show me how to write this better?

```
    1
   22
  333
 4444
55555
```

---

```
package basic;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows?");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        int num1 = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int k = n - 1; k >= i; k--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(num1);
            }
            System.out.println();
            num1 = num1 + 1;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this belongs on code review not stackoverflow

Comment: shouldn't it look like a real pyramid?

Comment: @Stefan - yes thank you for pointing it out. I have corrected It. XtremeBaumer - It looks though as a pyramid in the O/P.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions for Improvement

- Your num1 variable is unnecessary
- Unnecessary for loops.

  ```
  package basic;

  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Pattern {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the number of rows of the pyramid?");
      int n = scan.nextInt();

      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
          for (int j=1; j<=n;j++){
              if (j <= n-i){
                  System.out.print(" ");
              }else{
                  System.out.print(i);
              }
          }
          System.out.println()
      }

  }
  ```

Ouput : When input is 5

****1

***22

**333

*4444

55555